# How to transform data in many csv files and append the transformations to a different pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a main df that looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'], 'key2':[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3], 
'key3': [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3],})

Out[19]:
  key1  key2 key3
0   a    0   0
1   a    0   0
2   a    1   1
3   a    1   1
4   b    2   2
5   b    2   2
6   b    3   3
7   b    3   3
```

The main dataframe has many other columns other than the keys as well, but it didn't seem necessary to make a representation for them.

I also have many files that contain data relevent to the main dataframe. These files are organized very poorly and I have to create many new columns based off of what is in the files. Ulimately, the goal is to add those columns to the main dataframe, aligning the rows by all 3 key values.

I have many thousands of files to do this with however. I need to grab about 80 rows per file and 40 columns. My current strategy is to append all these rows to a dataframe that contains all the files I've already iterated through. But this takes a very long time.

I've also tried to just merge directly to the main dataframe.

Is there a faster way to do this? Or am I just stuck processing for hours and hours?

Ultimately, I want this:

```
   key1 key2 key3 madecolumn1   madecolumn2
0   a    0   0     0            0
1   a    0   0     1            1
2   a    1   1     2            2
3   a    1   1     3            3
4   b    2   2     4            4
5   b    2   2     5            5
6   b    3   3     6            6
7   b    3   3     7            7
```

Comment: Do you want to align the rows where madecolumn1 has the same value as the keys? Also are you grabbing the top 80 rows in your file?

Comment: Apart from the main dataframe, the dataframe i create from the csv files will have all three keys and about 40 madecolumns. I need the rows to align according to key value.  So keeping with the example posted... There will be a row from the csvs that I read in that has a 0 0 as the keys. and the values 0, 0 will be in madecolumn1 and madecolumn2 in that row.

Comment: I'll be grabbing every row in each file.

Comment: The main dataframe is ~500,000 rows and 250 columns. The files I read in will total the same 500,000 rows once they are all read in. With about 40 new columns to add the the main df. I have not read them all in. I am looking for a way that is faster than reading one at a time and appending until all are read and then one final merge. And also faster than reading one at a time and merge one at a time.

Comment: My intuition is you may want to work with the csv module to read in all the files and rolling in a merge while reading it in. The issue with merge in pandas, each time you call it is creating a new dataframe, so for large dataframes it becomes costly.

Comment: Is there some way I could use groupby to accomplish the merge? Such as group on the three keys in the maindf. And group on the keys in the csvs that are read in. And append based on matching groups.

Comment: I don't see how you can escape reading in your files, and appending it to your main df at each step. For a thousands of files, this itself will take a while.

Comment: If you can, create a new dataframe which is the right size, and then fill that in rather than doing multiple merges, as each merge will create a whole new dataframe in memory which takes a while

Comment: you can also set the key1, key2 and key3 as the index. If all the other dataframes have those to and the indexes match, then you can just merge them by doing `df['new column'] = column`